# Re-create (generic) member and populate/assign field member(s) via Java reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a set of classes with any number of non-custom members — just primitives, wrappers, etc.; some of them can be annotated with `@Encrypted` in order to be processed differently. All types implement `Envelope`.

I'm creating two `Map`s (based on a given type), storing the "field name" (as the key) and the "field value" (as the value).

The problem is when I try to recreate the types again based on the `Map`s. This is what I have so far:

```
import io.shido.domain.Envelope;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;

import java.util.Map;

public final class Factory<T extends Envelope> {
  private final Map<String, Object> regularMembers;

  private final Map<String, Object> secureMembers;

  public Factory(final Map<String, Object> regularMembers, final Map<String, Object> secureMembers) {
    this.regularMembers = regularMembers;
    this.secureMembers = secureMembers;
  }

  public T build() {
    try {
      final ParameterizedType superClass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass(); // This doesn't work >:(
      final Class<T> type = (Class<T>) superClass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
      final T result = type.newInstance();
      regularMembers.forEach((fieldName, fieldValue) -> assign(result, fieldName, fieldValue));
      secureMembers.forEach((fieldName, fieldValue) -> assign(result, fieldName, fieldValue));
      return result;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      logger.error("Cannot build type based on input parameters due to:", e);
      throw new IllegalStateException(e.toString());
    }
  }

  private void assign(final T type, final String fieldName, final Object fieldValue) {
    try {
      FieldUtils.getField(type.getClass(), fieldName).set(type, fieldValue);
    } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Any clues how to approach this? I can use any library.

---

The only restrictions I have is that the current types don't have setters — and I can't add those, and I'm using Java `8`.

For instance, this is an example:

```
public final class ExampleType implements Envelope {
  @Encrypted
  private String first;

  private String second;

  @Encrypted
  private String third;

  public ExampleType() { }

  public ExampleType(final String first, final String second, final String third) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.third = third;
  }

  public String getFirst() { return first; }

  public String getSecond() { return second; }

  public String getThird() { return third; }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be hitting a limitation of Java generics. The type `T` is not reified in your class at run time. What I've done in the past is ghetto, but require `Class<T> clazz` parameter in your class constructor and assign it to a field. This will enable you to new up the instance (assuming they have default/empty ctor)

Comment: `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` only works if the generic parameter is defined in the class hierarchy. So you need to have `class ExampleFactory extends Factory<ExampleType>`. Another option would be a type-token.

Comment: @derekmckinnon, I was entertaining something like that, but I thought that having the type `T` was enough. I was passing it in the constructor. If that's the only (simplest) way I can go for it...let me give it a whirl.

Comment: @x80486 in more elegant languages like C# (cue the flame war!) the `T` would be enough...but Java implemented generics in a way that wouldn't break pre-generics code. So unfortunately little workarounds are needed here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, try something like this (untested):

```
import io.shido.domain.Envelope;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;

import java.util.Map;

public final class Factory<T extends Envelope> {
  private final Class<T> clazz;

  private final Map<String, Object> regularMembers;

  private final Map<String, Object> secureMembers;

  public Factory(final Class<T> clazz, final Map<String, Object> regularMembers, final Map<String, Object> secureMembers) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.regularMembers = regularMembers;
    this.secureMembers = secureMembers;
  }

  public T build() {
    try {
      final T result = clazz.newInstance();
      regularMembers.forEach((fieldName, fieldValue) -> assign(result, fieldName, fieldValue));
      secureMembers.forEach((fieldName, fieldValue) -> assign(result, fieldName, fieldValue));
      return result;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      logger.error("Cannot build type based on input parameters due to:", e);
      throw new IllegalStateException(e.toString());
    }
  }

  private void assign(final T type, final String fieldName, final Object fieldValue) {
    try {
      FieldUtils.getField(type.getClass(), fieldName).set(type, fieldValue);
    } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally went that route...can't find a way to do it as I would like.

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are private I believe you need to make them accessible. in your try block:

```
Field f = FieldUtils.getField(type.getClass(), fieldName);
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(type, fieldValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to pass the class of the generic object (`Class<T>`) through the constructor and use it directly to instantiate it.

```
public final class Factory<T extends Envelope> {

    private Class<T> clazz;
    // maps omitted

    public Factory(Class<T> clazz, Map<String, Object> rm, Map<String, Object> sm) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.regularMembers = rm;
        this.secureMembers = sm;
    }
    ...
}
```

And then use [`Class::instance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) in the `T build()` method:

```
public T build() {

    try {
        final T result = clazz.newInstance();
        ...
    } ...
}
```